# Wirless stopped working in ubuntu 13.10 on hp pavillion dv6000

Tags: wireless

I'm using a Hp pavillion DV6000 running ubuntu 13.10 and it was working fine for a while but about an hour after it updated my wireless connection went out and when i go into the system settings it says it is on airplane mode which i can turn off by sliding the on/off switch but when i try to turn on the wireless it will not it will just slide right back to off when i let go of the mouse. it will not recognize that there are ant wireless networks but my the other computer i use which is a mac shows all networks around and can connect so it has to be a bug or something in ubuntu can someone please help me fix this very frustrating don't want to have to reinstall ubuntu on my computer again

Comment: soft was blocked but hard is still blocked how do i unblock hard cant do it through the gui system settings

Comment: nevermind im an idiot figured it out thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove hardblocked,you have to turn on the wifi switch.Try to find the wifi hardware switch to turn on wifi.After turn on the wifi hardware switch then run the below command to remove softblock,

```
sudo rfkill unblock wlan
```